# EF Core - Third type with required relationship between two others

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I'm using Entity Framework Core 7 (EF Core) for SQL Server, and I'm having a tough time figuring out how to configure relationships to meet a certain need. I'm sure I'm hardly the first person to try to accomplish this, so I'm either missing something in the documentation, or searching for the wrong things.

Example code:

```
public class House
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string StreetAddress { get; set; }
        public List<GaragePolicy> GaragePolicies { get; set; }
        public List<ParkingPermit> ParkingPermits { get; set; }
    }

    public class GaragePolicy
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public VehicleType VehicleType { get; set; }
        public int DurationDays { get; set; }
        public List<House> Houses { get; set; }
        public List<ParkingPermit> ParkingPermits { get; set; }
    }

    public class ParkingPermit
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int HouseId { get; set; }
        public House House { get; set; }
        public int GaragePolicyId { get; set; }
        public GaragePolicy GaragePolicy { get; set; }
    }

    /* Example data:
        House() { Id = 1, StreetAddress = "1234 Main Street", GaragePolicies = { 1 } }
        House() { Id = 2, StreetAddress = "5678 Front Street", GaragePolicies = { 1, 2 } }
            
        GaragePolicy() { Id = 1, VehicleType = VehicleType.Sedan, DurationDays = 7, Houses = { 1, 2 }
        GaragePolicy() { Id = 2, VehicleType = VehicleType.Truck, DurationDays = 7, Houses = { 2 }
        GaragePolicy() { Id = 3, VehicleType = VehicleType.Sedan, DurationDays = 30 }
    */
```

In this example, we have `House` and `GaragePolicy` entities. A `House` can have 0 or more `GaragePolicy`s assigned, and a `GaragePolicy` can be assigned to 0 or more Houses.

I have relationships and navigations working for these entities. EF Core detects the relationships, defines the database constraints, and automatically creates a join table.

Now, say that users can request a `ParkingPermit` for a House, based on a certain `GaragePolicy`. For example, someone who wanted to park their sedan on Main Street for a few days would likely pick the `House` with ID 1, and the `GaragePolicy` with ID 1.

**What I am looking to do is require that a `ParkingPermit` reference a `House` and `GaragePolicy` that are associated.** Based on the example data above, a `ParkingPermit` with a `HouseId` of 1 and a `GaragePolicyId` of 2 should fail, as the two entities are not associated.

Happy to do my own research if someone points me in the right direction. (I'm also new to Entity Framework, and only intermediate when it comes to C#/.NET in general, so it's entirely possible I'm approaching this the wrong way entirely.)

I have also tried creating an explicit join type entity. While this seems like using this type for creating relationships for the `ParkingPermit` type will work, I'm not sure how to still have direct navigations for the various types (e.g., `ParkingPermit` -> `House`, or `GaragePolicy` -> `ParkingPermit`s ).

Comment: Sounds like you need an explicit `House` <==> `GaragePolicy` many-to-many join table (eg a `ValidPermit` table with two one-many joins, though this can be defined as an ef core "skip navigation"). Then have `ParkingPermit` FK to the join table.

Comment: As Jeremy said you should set up many to many relationships between your entities, notice that there are conventional and explicit relationship mappings, both described [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/relationships/many-to-many#basic-many-to-many)